# How to get xournalpp's code documentation?

Tags: linux, documentation

I installed xournalpp like this in Debian:

```
sudo apt install doxygen
sudo apt install graphviz
sudo dpkg -i  xournalpp-1.0.20-hotfix-hotfix-Debian-buster-x86_64.deb
```

By entering the menu: `office--Xournal++`, I can run it.

Now I want to show its code documentation as [GitHub describes](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp):

```
Finally, type in doxygen in the root directory of the repository. 
The documentation can be found in doc/html and doc/latex.
```

What is the root directory of the repository?

```
sudo find  /  -name  'xournalpp'
/usr/share/xournalpp/ 
/usr/bin/xournalpp/
```

I tried `ls /usr/share/xournalpp/`:

```
tree /usr/share/xournalpp/ |grep doc
```

There is no `doc/html` or `doc/latex` in the  `/usr/share/xournalpp/`. How do I get `xournalpp`'s documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you're reading assume you have cloned the git repository, not installed it from your package manager. In this case, the "root directory of the repository" is whatever directory you were left with when you `git clone`d the repository.

Note that this is developer documentation, i.e. the functions and classes used by `xournalpp` - this is what the `doxygen` tool does. For user documentation, [consult their wiki on Github](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/wiki/User-Manual).